# who in mobile phone market allow me to upload my customly compiled linux kernel to my phone

Tags: android

i want to add some features to linux kernel to run on my mobile (android based mobile perhaps).
but i don't know who let me to upload my custom kernel. i want to buy such mobile phone.
some restrictions about uploading custom kernel to phone:
   1- replace existing kernel.
   2- can use my phones functionalities: it is due to some drivers are closed source and i must use the vendor's kernel to use it's drivers.
   3- ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADP1/ADP2 devices are probably your choice - they have unlocked bootloader, however they still have some binary components. HTC G1 and HTC Magic could be hacked with engineering bootloader and so run custom ROM, too. 
Some kernel sources for ADP1/ADP2 could be found here:
http://developer.htc.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are no markets that support uploading custom kernels.

This isn't a programming/development question.

If you've created a custom kernel for your device, you will need to distribute it yourself and I believe that the vendor drivers will need to be removed, since the Android kernel is open source but the drivers are not.

See [Cyanogenmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CyanogenMod)

Comment: if you look at N900 (maemo based) you can see that you can compile your custom kernel and upload it.